# copy attribute from line based on expression in line Python

Tags: python

```
import re
a = ('''
Gi1/0                          up             up       test
Fa2/0                          up             up       CloudInterface
Fa2/1                          up             up       CloudInterface
Fa3/0                          up             up       test
''')


for b in a:
    b = a.split("\n")
    for line in b:
        if 'CloudInterface' in b:
            line = b.split(' ') [0]
            print (line)
```

#

'''
How can i get the below values?

```
Fa2/0 
Fa2/1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you make many simple errors but you can try, and first is `for b in a:` -- loop char by char inside your `a` variable, remove it.

```
b = a.split("\n")
for line in b:
    if 'CloudInterface' in line:
        line1 = line.split(' ')[0]
        print (line1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using a list comprehension

You can use a list comprehension to do this:

```
[l.split(" ")[0] for l in a.split("\n") if "CloudInterface" in l]
```

which returns a list of the items:

```
['Fa2/0', 'Fa2/1']
```

The comprehension loops through each line by splitting at the `newlines` with `a.split('\n')`. On each line it then checks whether `"CloudInterface"` is in the line. If it is, return the string up to the first space with `l.split(' ')[0]`.

Hope this works for you and also when defining `'a'` at the beginning, you don't need the brackets:

```
a = '''
Gi1/0                          up             up       test
Fa2/0                          up             up       CloudInterface
Fa2/1                          up             up       CloudInterface
Fa3/0                          up             up       test
'''
```